# Tell socat to listen to connections from a single IP address

Tags: ip, socat

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:22,fork TCP:192.168.0.15:5900
```

How can I tell to `socat`, that port 22 is only trusted from the remote IP address 8.8.8.8, and it should not accept connections from other IP addresses? This is on a Linux server.

Comment: Note that there are [IP addresses explicitely reserved to be used in examples](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5737). 8.8.8.8 is google's.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add the `range` option to the socat listening address:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:22,fork,range=8.8.8.8/32 TCP:192.168.0.15:5900
```

Or you can add the `tcpwrap=vnc_forward` option and define global rules for that *`vnc_forward`* service as per [hosts_access(5)](https://www.mankier.com/5/hosts_access).

That won't stop the connections from reaching `socat`, but `socat` will ignore them (with a warning) if they don't come from 8.8.8.8.

Comment: WOW - that resolves my problem. thanks a lot!!

Comment: This no longer works in socat 1.8.0.0 as it refused to accept address like this when using `TCP-LISTEN`. Use `TCP4-LISTEN` to avoid this.

Answer (score 18):

Something like this works for me to make socat listen on localhost only.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:22,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 TCP:192.168.0.15:5900
```

So you could try this.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:22,fork,bind=8.8.8.8 TCP:192.168.0.15:5900
```

Comment: Your 2nd example doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to restrict the client addresses that are allowed to connect to the server. With `bind=8888` the socat-server would try to bind to the local interface 8.8.8.8 - which doesn't exist on the server side. Thus, `range=` as used in the [accepted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210745/1131) is the way to go.

Comment: This is because the title of the question is wrong : `listen connections from a single IP address` does not make sense, you do not listen on a IP address you do not own.

Answer (score 3):

Most people use firewalls for that. Have a look at `iptables` to restrict traffic to port 22 i.e.:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp '!' -s 8.8.8.8 --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Or, if the firewall is already restrictive, allow just one address:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 8.8.8.8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Please note that this is not a full configuration for an iptables firewall, you first need to setup a proper configuration before using the above.

Comment: Thank you. if i can use iptables i will use it too. But keep in mind why i mentioned micro-processors they strip all tools such as IPTables, SELinux etc because its micro embedded devices. as a result you have only few tools left such as socat only. But thank you.

Comment: I understand that not all tools will be available by default on some devices but in that case I would recommend you to configure the border firewall/router instead to avoid DDoS attacks. I like the answer of @Stéfane that it is possible to ignore sessions originating from other sources but that micro-processor of yours still need to do some processing.

Comment: @YumYumYum - those aren't tools - those are built-in kernel hooks. If you don't have [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org) in-kernel, and your trouble involves a low-power device and intrusion detection/protection, then you can bet that doing that work in userspace is gonna hurt that little device a lot more than it would do in kernel-space. You should build a kernel which better suits you.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary goal is security and you control the client machine then connecting to your socat server through an SSL tunnel is a safer bet, making the server verify the client cert before accepting connections.

I went through this recently trying to secure a synergy client/server setup.

This tutorial explains the setup clearly

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html

One deviation from the instructions that I found is your client SSL library should reject the server key by default due to the patch for logjam

Appending the following to the server PEM makes everything work

```
openssl dhparam 2048 >> "$FILENAME".pem
```

This key based exchange mechanism is much more authoritative when it comes to validating hosts over IP based auth.